# Un-Published items showing in Drupal search results (google search appliacne)

Tags: drupal, search, drupal-5, google-search-appliance

I inherited a Drupal 5 site recently and have a series of enhancements to make. Several of then revolve around search results.

1. Unpublished pages showing up in
   search engine results. Some of these
   are old pages, others are recently
   unpublished.  All are correctly
   marked as unpublished in the CMS and
   are still showing up.
2. Outdated pages are showing up from the search engine. The URL path structure changed and those items are old results in the DB.

From what I can tell the site uses Google Search Appliance(GSA) for the search rather than the default Drupal search. Is there a way I can be certain that it's using GSA other than seeing the module enabled?

If it is GSA it seems that I could get someone with access to the GSA to rebuild the search results on the site. Is this correct?

If rebuilding the search results is the right way to go about it, it seems whenever a fair amount of content is removed from the site I'll need to get someone to rebuild the search. Is there a better/automatic way?

Comment: Are the urls showing on search results still valid?
GSA will delete crawled contents if they return a 404 error when recrawling.
If those results come from a database feed, you can delete taht feed on the GSA's admin console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it's drupal that is handling the search. Google would need db access to show unpublished nodes. It could be you are using views to do search but forgot to only take published nodes.

If Drupal is handling the searchyou just need to flush and rebuild the search index. This can be done without too much trouble if you don't have too much content.

Comment: It turns out that permissions are off and anonymous users can access that content so it may be something else.

Comment: How would you filter out unpublished nodes from a search view? One only can filter on the index, no?

Answer (score 1):

The GSA could still be showing deleted content depending on what your data source is.

If the content is coming from a database feed and is then dropped from the query it would be dropped.  If the content was coming from a natural crawl or through a custom connector feed it would not be removed from the index on delete.  Instead it needs to naturally cycle out of the index which can take a while.

One way to block deleted url's from being displayed is to do it through the front end.  In the GSA Admin interface go to Serving > Front Ends then choose your front end and click the Remove URL tab.  You can either list your url's or block a group of url's through regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted an answer to your [more general question concerning node access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615405/drupal-is-allowing-viewing-of-unpublished-content). The problem with your search results might well be related to that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the Google Appliance more up to date, you might try out [XmlSiteMap](http://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap), a module that publishes a proper xml sitemap for all your content.

For an online website, publishing a sitemap is a good way to keep the search engines up to date, as they can use it to know about new pages and to purge old pages. I'm assuming that the Google Appliance would use this too,.